# Three.js LoadingManager onProgress only working after finished?

Tags: javascript, three.js, progress-bar, loading, gltf

I'm trying to make a loading screen with an `HTML` progress bar in Three.js. I use a `THREE.LoadingManager()` to pass into my `GLTFLoader`. I use the `onProgress` method to get when every model is loaded, but it doesn't seem to work. It only works at the end, once everything is loaded (so basically it jumps from 0% to 98%). I think it has something to do with me using a wrapper function.

Here is my code:

```js
let loadingManager = new THREE.LoadingManager();

loadingManager.onProgress = function(url, loaded, total){
    document.getElementById('loading-progress').value = Math.round((loaded / total) * 100);
    document.getElementById('loading-progress-label').innerHTML = `${Math.round((loaded / total) * 100)}%`;
}

let loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader(loadingManager);

function load(asset, pos=[0, 0, 0], rot=[-Math.PI / 2, Math.PI, Math.PI], scale=[5, 5, 5], appendTo){
    loader.load(`Assets/${asset}.glb`, function(object){
        object.scene.position.set(pos[0], pos[1], pos[2]);
        object.scene.rotation.set(rot[0], rot[1], rot[2]);
        object.scene.scale.set(scale[0], scale[1], scale[2]);
        object.scene.name = asset;

        scene.add(object.scene);

        if(appendTo != undefined){
            appendTo.push(object.scene);
        }
    });
};

//Decoration
load('platform_grass', [-5, 4, -0.5]);
load('platform_grass', [-2, 3, -0.5], undefined, [5, 10, 5]);
load('rock_largeA', [1, 3, -1], undefined, [2, 2, 2]);
load('plant_bushDetailed', [-5, 1, -1], undefined, [3, 3, 3]);
load('plant_bushDetailed', [-2, 6, -1], undefined, [3, 3, 3]);
```

I'm pretty sure the problem has to do with me using the `load()` function, rather than manually loading each asset. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The LoadingManager docs](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/loaders/managers/LoadingManager)
actually say:

> onProgress — (optional) this function will be called when an item is **complete**.

Try passing a second callback function to the loader (which will act as your progress callback).

Here is what works for me:

```js
const loadingManager = new THREE.LoadingManager()
const loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader(loadingManager)

loader.load(
    gltfPath,
    // on load handler
    async (gltf) => {
        // Do whatever you want with the glTF
    },
    // on progress handler
    (xhr) => {
        const progressXHR = xhr.loaded / xhr.total
        // ...
    }
)
```

Here is what your code would look like when using the approach above:

```js
const loadingManager = new THREE.LoadingManager();
const loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader(loadingManager);
let loadedCount = 0;

const toLoad = [
    { asset: 'platform_grass', pos: [-5, 4, -0.5] },
    { asset: 'platform_grass', pos: [-2, 3, -0.5], rot: undefined, scale: [5, 10, 5] },
    { asset: 'rock_largeA', pos: [1, 3, -1], rot: undefined, scale: [2, 2, 2] },
    { asset: 'plant_bushDetailed', pos: [-5, 1, -1], rot: undefined, scale: [3, 3, 3] },
    { asset: 'plant_bushDetailed', pos: [-2, 6, -1], rot: undefined, scale: [3, 3, 3] },
];

function load(asset, pos=[0, 0, 0], rot=[-Math.PI / 2, Math.PI, Math.PI], scale=[5, 5, 5], appendTo) {
    loader.load(`Assets/${asset}.glb`, (object) => {
        loadedCount++;
        object.scene.position.set(pos[0], pos[1], pos[2]);
        object.scene.rotation.set(rot[0], rot[1], rot[2]);
        object.scene.scale.set(scale[0], scale[1], scale[2]);
        object.scene.name = asset;

        scene.add(object.scene);

        if (appendTo !== undefined) {
            appendTo.push(object.scene);
        }
    }, (xhr) => {
        const progress = Math.round(((xhr.loaded / xhr.total + loadedCount) / toLoad.length) * 100);
        document.getElementById('loading-progress').value =  progress;
        document.getElementById('loading-progress-label').innerHTML = `Loaded ${progress}%`;
    });
};

toLoad.forEach((item) => load(item.asset, item.pos, item.rot, item.scale));
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! Could you modify my load() function?

Comment: @Halo Sure. Done, I just updated my answer a couple of times. I hope the current version works for you. It aggregates the total loading progress.

Answer (score 1):

Pass the `onProgress` callback to the loader as a second param.

See https://threejs.org/docs/?q=gltfloa#examples/en/loaders/GLTFLoader

```js
function onProgress(url, loaded, total){
    document.getElementById('loading-progress').value = Math.round((loaded / total) * 100);
    document.getElementById('loading-progress-label').innerHTML = `${Math.round((loaded / total) * 100)}%`;
}

function load(asset, pos=[0, 0, 0], rot=[-Math.PI / 2, Math.PI, Math.PI], scale=[5, 5, 5], appendTo){
    const assetUrl = `Assets/${asset}.glb`;
    loader.load(assetUrl, function(object){
        object.scene.position.set(pos[0], pos[1], pos[2]);
        object.scene.rotation.set(rot[0], rot[1], rot[2]);
        object.scene.scale.set(scale[0], scale[1], scale[2]);
        object.scene.name = asset;

        scene.add(object.scene);

        if(appendTo != undefined){
            appendTo.push(object.scene);
        }
    }, function(xhr){
       onProgress(assetUrl, xhr.loaded, xhr.total);
    }, function(error){
       // your code to handle error
    });
};
```

Hope this helps!